# Trying to use .map to upper case the first letter of every word in an array

Tags: javascript

I just cant get the code right, here is what i have tried...

```
function titleCase(str) {

  var newStrArr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var updateStr = newStrArr.map(function (x) {
    return x[0].toUpperCase();
  });
  return updateStr;
}
```

Comment: `index` seems to be a variable, is there more code to this? Is it possible `index` is declared somewhere earlier on in the code ?

Comment: Could you share the full snippet where you saw this?

Comment: String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};


function titleCase(str) {
    var newTitle = str.split(' ');
    var updatedTitle = [];
    for (var st in newTitle) {
        updatedTitle[st] = newTitle[st].toLowerCase().replaceAt(0, newTitle[st].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
    }
    return updatedTitle.join(' ');
}

Comment: off topic: imo `replaceAt` has a too narrow use case to add it to the String prototype. And the function `titleCase` is too complicated. `function titleCase(str) { return str.replace(/S+/g, word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase()) }` does the same as your whole code, @ajhernandez95

Comment: can you explain that code?

Comment: @ajhernandez95 `return str.replace(...)` return the string with a few replacements done. `/S+/g` is a regular expression matching every sequence of non-whitespace characters, like your code uses `.split(' ')` to get these strings. And `word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase()` is an *(arrow)* function that takes a string and returns the first character in uppercase + the rest lowercase. in contrast to you converting the whole string to lowercase, and then replacing the first character with its uppercase counterpart.

Comment: @Thomas What exactly is word and .slice? i am not familiar with these.

Comment: @ajhernandez95 `word` is the function argument, the passed "word" to convert to titleCase. And [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is like `substring()`, only a more common name, as you'll find this method on different classes, like Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`index` is just a variable is (variable name does not need to match its meaning, yet it should for many reasons). And it's being passed as `finish` argument to `substr()` then it tells somehow what is meaning of its value. Unfortunately w/o seeing the code I can only guess that it tries to look for i.e. certain character in the string and then take the substring ending at that character (say looking for `@` in email address and then take out that part that prepends `@`).